Evaluating $\lim_{z\to\ -1+2i} (z+1-2i) \frac{ze^{iπz}}{z^2+2z+5}$
I can having trouble finding the solution to the following limit as it is in my worked problems set:
$$
\lim_{z\to\ -1+2i} (z+1-2i) \frac{ze^{iπz}}{z^2+2z+5}=(-1+2i)\frac{e^{-iπ-2π}}{4i}
$$
Getting the exponent and denominator parts are simple, but the factor of e is not.
The first thing I did was to immediately plug in for z which led to (-1+2i+1−2)=0. Clearly not the right way to solve this, I then distributed the factor to the numerator getting this:
$$
\lim_{z\to\ -1+2i} \frac{z^2e^{iπz}+ze^{iπz}-2ize^{iπz}}{z^2+2z+5}
$$
Trying to plug in now however still does not lead me to the worked solution, but to this:
$$
\lim_{z\to\ -1+2i} \frac{z^2e^{iπz}+ze^{iπz}-2ize^{iπz}}{z^2+2z+5}=\frac{(-3)e^{-iπ-2π}+(-1+2i)e^{-iπ-2π}+(2i+4)e^{-iπ-2π}}{4i}= \frac{(4i)e^{-iπ-2π}}{4i}=e^{-iπ-2π}
$$
What am I failing to see or do properly to find the worked answer of:
$$
(-1+2i)\frac{e^{-iπ-2π}}{4i}
$$
This limit is part of a larger problem on evaluating an integral using calculus of residue.
Additional question: Should I never try to plug in for the variable of a limit as I first did (giving me =0) before I have distributed/expanded the function within the limit?

We have
$$
z^2+2z+5=(z+1-2\mathrm i)(z+1+2\mathrm i)
$$
so that
$$
(z+1-2\mathrm i) \frac{z \,\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi z}}{z^2+2z+5}=z\cdot\frac{ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi z}}{z+1+2\mathrm i}.
$$
Now you can just plug in $z=-1+2\mathrm i$ to get
$$
\lim_{z\to -1+2\mathrm i}(z+1-2\mathrm i) \frac{z \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi z}}{z^2+2z+5}=(-1+2\mathrm i)\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi (-1+2\mathrm i)}}{(-1+2\mathrm i)+1+2\mathrm i}=(-1+2\mathrm i)\frac{\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi -2\pi}}{4\mathrm i}.
$$

Thank you! I shouldn't have disregarded the denominator as soon as I got it to match the RHS.
